# How do I move vCenter Server Appliance to a vDS?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I am trying to migrate both the only vCSA and the VMKernel interface in my ESXi host from a standard vSwitch to a vDS, and that gave me all kinds of mess. How to do that properly? Bear in mind that the host in question also have the virtual machine that performs as the router.

My intended setup:

The host:

```
                     [      ]- vmnic0 -+- LACP --- Switch 1 (managed)
Internet --- vmnic3 -[ Host ]- vmnic1 -+
                     [      ]- vmnic2 --- Switch 2 (unmanaged)
```

vSwitch0:

```
vmnic3 --[ vSwitch0 ]-- vRouter
```

vDS:

```
vmnic0 -+- LAG1 --[     ]-- vRouter
vmnic1 -+         [ vDS ]-- vCSA
         vmnic2 --[     ]-- vmk0 (management network)
```

vRouter (OS: Ubuntu Linux):

```
vSwitch0 --[ vRouter ]-- vDS
```

vCSA (and other VMs):

```
vDS --[ vCSA ]
```

Other physical computers are attached on `Switch1` or `Switch2`. There is also another ESXi host.

Comment: Do you only have a single host?

Comment: @ewwhite There are two hosts but the second host is only on when there is the need for it.

Comment: If you're just experimenting and want to use a vDS, that's fine, but can you explain why you need a distributed switch in this setup?

Comment: @ewwhite The only way ESXi can support LACP is vDS and that second host, when on, joins the vDS too

Comment: Yes, I understand how distributed switches and LACP work. But I don't see the use case here.

Comment: If only VMWare created plenty of perfectly decent documentation and training on exactly how to do this...

Comment: @ewwhite I need LACP to keep file transfers from saturating the network link and rendering my network unuseable. Noticed how the router is part of the VM? There is also an NAS VM.

Comment: How does you current setup look like, can you show us some screenshots? Do you control the switches, that is can you configure them and enable / disable LACP?

Comment: @MarioLenz I have to tear that setup down so I can get my Internet access up. And yes I control all gear here.

Comment: What ESXi version are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Caveat:

*I don't think a distributed switch or LACP belong here. And this definitely doesn't sound like an environment with VMware Enterprise licensing...*

But use the network migration tool in VMware. This is [fully-documented](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc%2FGUID-0E5B9FC3-5176-4223-8F08-3C3F08C12ECD.html) and a supported means of migrating virtual and physical adapters from Standard vSwitches to vDS.

Comment: That tool did not work for me as I am migrating either the sole VMKernel adapter or the vCSA itself. Such migration creates a network outage. Is there anything to do with the vDS uplink (that is, vDS uplink being incompatible with normal traffic)

Comment: Also, this migration shouldn't involve an outage. But honestly, I'm not sure what you're doing. Can you take a screenshot of your network layout?

Comment: I think he is trying to get vcenter to migrate it's own network, this will trigger an outage and anuto roll back I think. He should probably just create a new network, and directly log into the host using the fat client to move the VM (VCSA) to the new network

Comment: No, it won't cause an outage if done to the documentation guidelines. But this setup seems a little too outside the norm and is not a good candidate for a distributed switch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't follow your question very well, but I will make a suggestion all the same.

If VC looses network connection during a network reconfig, the change is automatically reverted (sometimes), even if it is only for a moment.

I would suggest putting your VCSA onto a temporary second network (so you have two routes), this way you can stop using the primary net while you do the moving around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should migrate in two steps, first to a vDS without LACP and then enable LACP. The first step should be straight-forward: Create the vDS and port groups you need and set vmnic0 as the first uplink and migrate your vmknics and vCenter to the vDS. Then set vmnic1 as the second uplink for your vDS. Then [migrate to LACP](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-45DF45A6-DBDB-4386-85BF-400797683D05.html).

I've stumbled on an interesting blog posting recently: [Disabling vSphere vDS Network Rollback](http://vwud.net/2016/02/16/disabling-vsphere-vds-network-rollback/). Maybe this can help you, too.